# Split integral domain function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integratechangevariables

Sometimes we would like to split the domain of a definite integral into two (or more) regions, for instance to exploit symmetry or otherwise produce two (or more) simpler integrals.  I can do this "by hand," by explicitly cutting and pasting the integrand into two hand-crafted integrals with the limits I seek.

I'm seeking an algorithmic method to do this (so I can use it in a function call).

Imagine we have a difficult definite integral, `int = ....` whose limits happen to be $0$ and $a$.  I'd like a function with arguments as follows:

```
IntegrateSplitDomain[int_, break_] := ....
```

where `int` is the complete integral.  A call such as:

```
IntegrateSplitDomain[ Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, a}], a/2]
```

would produce

```
Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, a/2}] + Integrate[x^2, {x, a/2, a}]
```

It is also acceptable to produce a `List` of the component integrals, i.e.,

```
{Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, a/2}], Integrate[x^2, {x, a/2, a}]}
```

Which I can sum using `Total`.

This `List` form allows me to process each separately... for instance using `IntegrateChangeVariables[]` with different parameters on each component integral.

Anyway... how do I implement `IntegrateSplitDomain`?

---

The more general case is to split the integral into an arbitrary number of domains, for instance to get three equal domains, as in:

```
IntegrateSplitDomain[int, {a/3, 2 a/3}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SetAttributes[IntegrateSplitDomainList, HoldFirst];

IntegrateSplitDomainList[
   Integrate[expr_, {sym_Symbol, lb_, ub_}, opts___], break_] := 
  Module[{breaks},
   If[IntegerQ[break] && break > 1, breaks = Range[lb, ub, (ub - lb)/break],
    If[VectorQ[break],
     breaks = Flatten[{lb, break, ub}]]]; 
   Inactive[Integrate][expr, {sym, #[[1]], #[[2]]}, opts] & /@ 
    Partition[breaks, 2, 1]];
```

For evenly spaced intervals,

```
IntegrateSplitDomainList[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, a}], 4]
```

[image]

```
% // Activate

(* {a^3/192, (7 a^3)/192, (19 a^3)/192, (37 a^3)/192} *)

% // Total

(* a^3/3 *)
```

For specified breaks,

```
IntegrateSplitDomainList[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, a}], {a/4, a/2}]
```

[image]

```
% // Activate

(* {a^3/192, (7 a^3)/192, (7 a^3)/24} *)

% // Total

(* a^3/3 *)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks very much.  ($+1, \checkmark$)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood you right. Is this what you mean?

```
integrateSplitDomain[integrand_, from_, to_, n_Integer?Positive, 
                     x_Symbol] := Module[{intervals, m},

  intervals = Subdivide[to - from, n];
  First@Last@
    Reap@Do[Sow@
       Inactive[Integrate][
        integrand, {x, intervals[[m]], intervals[[m + 1]]}],
      {m, 1, Length[intervals] - 1}
      ]
  
  ]
```

Call it as

```
integrateSplitDomain[Sin[x], 0, a, 3, x]
```

[image]

```
integrateSplitDomain[Sin[x]*Exp[x/2], 0, a, 6, x]
```

[image]

Now you can post process this result as you want. Convert to `Sum` and eventually activatate.

Comment: This is very helpful ($+1$)... but your function demands I input the integrand separately.  I'd like the function to take an entire definite *integral* (with its limits), extract the original limits, replace them, as described.  By analogy, `IntegrateChangeVariables` takes as input a *full* integral (with limits).  My example operates on `int` (a full integral).  Clear?

Answer (score 2):

````
IntegrateSplitDomain[int_, break_] := 
 Module[{integrand = int[[1, 1]], var = int[[1, 2, 1]], limits = int[[1, 2, 2 ;; 3]]},
  Integrate[integrand, {var, limits[[1]], break}] + 
   Integrate[integrand, {var, break, limits[[2]]}]
  ]

IntegrateSplitDomain[Hold@Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, a}], a/2]
 (* a^3/3 *)
```
````